# Does tensorflow have the function similar to pytorch's "masked_fill_"

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I want to set INF value to matrix by mask matrix, just like pytorch code:

```
scores.data.masked_fill_(y_mask.data, -float('inf'))
```

I try to use `tf.map_fn` to implement that, but the performance is too slow. So does tensorflow have any efficient function to implement that?

Comment: I don't see any direct method but you can simply do it if you have the mask indices which you want to fill in using a specific value. you can see this example - https://gist.github.com/jihunchoi/f1434a77df9db1bb337417854b398df1.

Answer (score 3):

I have used a math calculate method to instead. It's valid and much faster.

```
def mask_fill_inf(matrix, mask):
    negmask = 1 - mask
    num = 3.4 * math.pow(10, 38)
    return (matrix * mask) + (-((negmask * num + num) - num))
```

Do anyone have the better method?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use:

```
tf.where(mask, default_value, data)
```

reference:https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41617

Answer (score 0):

I am inspired by the above answer.

`masked_fill` ==>

```
def mask_fill_inf(matrix, mask):
    num = 3.4 * math.pow(10, 38)
    return (matrix + (-(((mask * num) + num) - num)))
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this one

```
def masked_fill(tensor, mask, value):
    return tf.where(mask, tf.fill(tf.shape(tensor), value), tensor)
```